# Recommended pattern when method modifies an argument

Tags: oop

Let's say I'm creating a class called SomeLibrary. This class has a method Calculate, which takes one argument - an instance of SomeClass.

```
class SomeLibrary 
{
    void Calculate(SomeClass argument) 
    {
        //Some algorithm...

        //argument's value is changed!
        argument.value = 3;
    }
}
```

Result of Calculate is a modified SomeClass. How to inform the user about it? I see 2 solutions:

1. Return SomeClass instead of void - in this case, argument still is being modifed, but this time it's being returned also. Downside of this is that user might not expect the argument to be modified, maybe he needs to retain the version of it before the modification.
2. In the Calculate a deep copy of argument could be done and this one would be returned. However, creating a deep copy is not always a simple task.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to embrace OOP, you need to coexist with *mutation*. That is, you give an instance of something, usually one will expect that it'll be mutated. There's no problem with that.

Unless your own docs says the opposite, mutation is fine. Otherwise, you might want to take a look at [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I don't really understand what AutoMapper has to do with the topic?

Comment: @Loreno It has an important relationship: if you need to create new instances and map previous data to the new instance, you can use that library to save time :D

Comment: @Loreno Sure, that's it